# UITableView Smooth Scrolling Issue Because of "tableView:willDisplayCell: Method"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, smooth-scrolling

As it's clear from the title, I have a scrolling performance issue in a table view.
Since I have read nearly every question that is posted online in this regard, and I assume all of you have much more experience with UITableView and its techniques, I won't bother with general stuff, and I just wanna point out some key things in my code that may help you help me spot where I'm doing wrong.

- The UI in each cell is very very basic, so rendering each doesn't take considerable time. No shadows, no rounded corners, no extra effect, nothing. Just a few labels and two images, that's all.
- The datasource is an `NSArray` which is already fetched from CoreData. The data of the labels are set from the content of the array, without much calculations or process required.
- The height is each cell is a static integer, so the `tableView:HeightForRowAtIndexPath:` will immediately return the result as fast as possible. No calculations required.
- The `tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath:` dequeues and reuses cell with reusable identifiers so any re-creation is avoided.

So far everything is perfectly smooth. The issue is where items in Core Data are fetched from a server (Which is extremely fast) as user scrolls down. Data binding is done inside `tableView:willDisplayCell:atIndexPath:` to prevent `tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath:` from becoming slow, as data needs to be loaded just before the cell goes live on the screen. I also fetch new items from server inside this method whenever there're some cells remaining till the last item fetched. So for example when there are totally 50 cells data fetched and put in the CoreData already and this method is called for cell number let's say 40, I request another 50 cell data from server, so that it will be ready whenever user reaches the end of the table.

As I expect this should only be called for the cells that go live on the screen. But putting some `NSLog`s shows that it is called multiple times until next 200 cells data are fetched (I guess the amount changes depending on device or simulator and the memory available on them and also OS limits). For example, I'm testing on an iPhone 7+, and I start the app and I go the page in which the table is. It fetches first 50 items and only first 4 items are shown on the screen, But I see that `tableView:willDisplayCell:atIndexPath:` is also called for cell #25, so another 50 is fetched immediately, and then it is called for cell #75, so another 50 is fetched, and this goes on for like first 200-300 cells, and then when fetching is stopped, scrolling is extremely fast and optimized until next 200-300 cells are fetched.

What can I do? Shouldn't `tableView:willDisplayCell:atIndexPath:` fire whenever a cell is about to be displayed? Where else should I fetch data as user scrolls?

Any ideas or suggestions is REALLY and GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Data binding is normally done in cellForRowAtIndexPath. This is also only called just before a cell actually displays. As for your current issue, I don't know, hard to say. Perhaps your table view bounds extend beyond the screen edge?

Comment: Thanks for your time Jordan. First the table bound is not extended beyond the screen edge. It doesn't reach the screen edge. Second, regarding data binding, U are right, I myself usually do that in cellForRowAtIndexPath. But in this case, after getting stuck with this I tried willDisplayCell, because I saw that cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called only before the cell goes live. Both methods are called for many more cells before they even come close to being shown on the screen ! It's driving me crazy !!!

Comment: Both of those methods are only called before the cell goes live. There's something new in iOS 10 that tries to predict what cells will go live before they actually do but that wouldn't call quite that far in advance.

Comment: That sounds related! Is there any way to disable this feature in iOS 10?

Comment: I don't think this is your issue. It's designed to make scrolling smoother, not choppier. You haven't posted any code, I'm guessing you're doing something wrong somewhere that's causing the table view to try and create too many cells in advance.

Comment: What part of code do you wanna see ?